# How can I insert a large vertical brace in a single cell of a one column and two rows table?

Tags: tables, braces

I need a fixed size table of one column and two rows per page, where I can contain a large vertical brace surrounding a series of items in each cell (x2).

Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[10pt, b6paper, twoside, openright]{memoir}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1.25cm}{.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{1.5cm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout{}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[main=latin]{babel}
\begin{document}
\[
    \left. \begin{array}{l}
        \textrm{Welcome}\\
        \textrm{
            \hspace*{1em}to
        }\\
        \textrm{latex}
    \end{array}\right\}
    \textbf{\textcolor{red}R}. \textbf{username}
\]
    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{l}
                \input{itemstext1} \\
                \input{itemstext2}
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

In the itemstext1 file for input, I have:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
%\[
$
    \left. \begin{array}{l}
        \textrm{Welcome}\\
        \textrm{friend!}
    \end{array}\right\}
    \textbf{\textcolor{red}R}. \textbf{name}
%\]
$
\end{document}
```

In the itemstext2 file for input, I have:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
%\[
$
    \left. \begin{array}{l}
        \textrm{Welcome}\\
        \textrm{
            \hspace*{1em}back
        }\\
        \textrm{friend!}
    \end{array}\right\}
    \textbf{\textcolor{red}R}. \textbf{middle name}
%\]
$
\end{document}
```

The brace code works outside the table.  However, it doesn't work inside it, and it returns an `Missing $ inserted` error at the opening and closing of the brace code.

**EDIT**:
I was able to make it work according to @david-carlisle, however I haven't found the way to fix the size of the table.

Comment: do you want your items to be  in the same cell of the table, if so you can the same `\left\right` form that you show, in `$...$` not `\[...\]` as an `l` column is like `mbox` and can not have display math. If it is the entire table just do the same outside thetabular, `$\left.\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}\right\}$`

Comment: Please, can you put a full minimal compilable code? In math-mode is to use \mathrm or \text: in fact the commands are: \mathbf (bold), \mathit (cursive), \mathrm=\text.